# How to deal with multiple features from multiple sources over multiple days?

Tags: python, machine-learning

I am relatively new to ML so I hope this isn't too basic.

I work for a software company and am looking to model user health and retention. Basically, every user signs a contract with us for 12 months. So for each user, we have a set of their activities over their 12 months with us, following that 12 months they either renew their contract (positive) or churn from our service (negative).

I figured I can build a supervised classification model that gives a client health score (out of 100) with the score representing the users percentage chance of renewing their contract. Ideally this score would look at a moving set of 30 days of user data. This way, we could model health scores for users early in their contract, not just those at the time of renewal.

I am however, getting stuck in how to think about organizing the data given that each user set is essentially a massive matrix with dates vs activities - so how to think about each model being either a positive or negative. Should I create an array of dataframes in python? What would be the first couple steps here?

Feel free to say if I'm off track / barking up the wrong tree, or if this isn't the wrong forum for seeking general help rather than for a code issue. Thanks!

Comment: What's in the user data, and how do you calculate the health score based on that?

Comment: The user data contains various metrics around user activity - which is calibrated daily. Eg actions taken per day, unique interactions per day, sessions per day.

Ideally, i'd like to calculate an arbitrary health score for each user based on this data. So in theory, a user that logs in every day and is successful on our platform might have a health score of 100, whereas, a user that doesn't log in and isn't successful, might have a health score of 0.